# facebook publish action but without redirect

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

The flow of action on my site is:

- a user finds something they want on any website
- they click a browser button which opens an iframe with content from my site and allows the user to add the item they were looking at to a list
- (at this point my system does the work to add details to the db)

  the user then clicks to close the iframe and carries on doing what they were

When a user chooses to add something i want to also publish the action to facebook timeline

I use the following code which works as it should, but, once it has completed the task it redirects to a predetermined url - named $my_url

The problem is I want this action posting to happen seamlessly as my user has an iframe pop up open which at this point is saying "***** has been added successfully to your list"

So can I stop it redirecting and make it just a background operation? I can't redirect to what the user is already looking at either which was one idea as you have to own the url inside the fb app

This is the code I'm using

```
$app_id = "_APP_ID_";
$app_secret = "_SECRET";
$my_url = "http://*******.com/pages/add.html";
$og_url = "http://*******.com/pages/view?id=$new_id";

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

if(empty($code)) {
$dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
. $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) 
. &scope=email,user_birthday,friends_birthday,user_likes,friends_likes,publish_stream";

echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
                }

$token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
. $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
. "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
. "&code=" . $code;

$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

// remove the @expires
$params = null;
parse_str($access_token, $params);
$access_token_updated = $params['access_token'];

$post_data = "wish=" . $og_url . "&access_token=" . $access_token_updated;

// setup the curl
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/*******:add');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

// execute the curl
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
if(curl_error($ch))
{
//echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch) . "<br/>";
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Is there another way around this?

Comment: It’s not publishing the action, that gets the user redirected – but the server-side login you are doing there. If you don’t like that, switch to client-side login, using a popup.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did...

Change all code in OP and replace with this and all ok:

```
include 'path_to/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'=>'__APPID__',
'secret'=>'__SECRET__',
'cookie'=>true
));

if(!$facebook->getUser())
{
$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'email,publish_actions'));
echo "<script> top.location=\"".$url."\"; </script>";
exit(0);
}

$params = array("OBJECT_NAME"=>"http://*****.com/view?id=$new_id","access_token"=>$facebook->getAccessToken());

$out = $facebook->api('/me/NAMESPACE:ACTION_NAME','post',$params);
```